# How to resolve "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lookup')" during npm install

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, operating-system

I am trying to do npm install on a newly cloned angular project , the npm install is success , but while invoking the application using ng s, I am facing the below error with the node_modules. Is it something to do with the Node js version?

```
\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:789
        var charset = mime.charsets.lookup(value.split(';')[0]);
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lookup')
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:789:37)
    at setHeaderForResponse (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\dist\utils\compatibleAPI.js:94:9)
    at processRequest (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\dist\middleware.js:142:11)
    at ready (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\dist\utils\ready.js:17:5)
    at middleware (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\dist\middleware.js:69:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
    at C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at Server.setHeaders (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:2944:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
    at C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
    at param (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
    at param (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:376:14)
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:421:3)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:136:14)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:1948:18
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at next (C:\Users\N121075\class-ui\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)

Node.js v18.14.0
```

Below are the versions installed:
**Angular CLI: 15.2.9
Node: 18.14.0
Package Manager: npm 9.3.1
OS: win32 x64**

Comment: I have angular 15 and Node 18 installed which is actually compatible right?

Answer (score 0):

You can try cleaning cache once using npm like below:

```
npm cache clean --force
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```

Comment: Not working....

Comment: Try updating angular cli